# Aggregate and group by $month the mongodb nested data:

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have nested data as below.

```
{"event":{
            "timestamp":"2020-01-01T08:36:29",
            "counters":[
                {
                    "name":"launches",
                    "value":100
                },
                {
                    "name":"cok",
                    "value":10
                },
            ]
        }
    },


{
    "event":{
            "timestamp":"2020-01-15T10:36:37",
            "counters":[
                {
                    "name":"launches",
                    "value":150
                },
                {
                    "name":"cok",
                    "value":20
                }
            ]
        }
    },


{
        "event":{
            "timestamp":"2020-02-01T12:36:44",
            "counters":[
                {
                    "name":"launches",
                    "value":250
                },
                {
                    "name":"cok",
                    "value":35
                }
            ]
        }
    },


{
        "event":{
            "timestamp":"2020-02-22T14:36:52",
            "counters":[
                {
                    "name":"launches",
                    "value":350
                },
                {
                    "name":"cok",
                    "unit":"count",
                    "value":50
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

After aggregation we are expecting result like

Jan month expecting result like

```
{
    "event":{
        "timestamp":"2020-01-15T10:36:37",
        "counters":[
            {
                "name":"launches",
                "value":150         **(1st document value - last document value of the month)**
            },
            {
                "name":"cok",
                "unit":"count",
                "value":10          (1st document value - last document value of the month)
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Feb month expecting result like

```
{
    "event":{
        "timestamp":"2020-02-22T14:36:52",
        "counters":[
            {
                "name":"launches",
                "value":100         (1st document value - last document value of the month)
            },
            {
                "name":"cok",
                "unit":"count",
                "value":40          (1st document value - last document value of the month)
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

We want to get single document group by month and the counters value should be like 1st document value of the month - last document value of the month

Comment: Have you tried anything? Perhaps with [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html#first-aggregation) or [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/index.html#last-aggregation)

Comment: No actually I am very new on mongodb. I tried $group and aggregate but I am not able to achieve